# GD image library not loaded, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, gd

My Drupal installations are complaining over missing GD library:

```
GD library rotate and desaturate effects
The GD library for PHP is missing or outdated. Check the PHP image documentation for information on how to correct this.
```

However I have installed the gd package with

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

and restarted Apache several times.

It shows over the list of installed packages: 
Packages:

```
dpkg -l|grep php
ii  libapache2-mod-php5                 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14              amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii  php-pear                            5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14              all          PEAR - PHP Extension and Application Repository
ii  php5                                5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14              all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php5-cgi                            5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14              amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
ii  php5-cli                            5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14              amd64        command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
ii  php5-common                         5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14              amd64        Common files for packages built from the php5 source
ii  php5-gd                             5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14              amd64        GD module for php5
ii  php5-json                           1.3.2-2build1                       amd64        JSON module for php5
ii  php5-mysql                          5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14              amd64        MySQL module for php5
ii  php5-readline                       5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14              amd64        Readline module for php5
```

When trying to add the library manually to a php.ini file with

```
extension=ge.so;
```

I get this warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/ge.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/ge.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Server has been installed with Virtualmin GPL

```
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
```

PHP version:

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
```

Any advice very appreciated!

Comment: That should be `extension=gd.so` not `extension=ge.so;`.

Comment: You are right, it works now. Thanks for your help! btw - the file I changed was `/etc/php5/mods-available/gd.ini`.